# How to extract properties used in a Expression<Func<T, TResult>> query and test their value?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, func

I need to create a function to evaluate queries for some rules before executing them. Here's the code:

```
public class DataInfo
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new DataInfo()
        {
            A = 10,
            B = 5,
            C = -1
        };

        // the result should be -1
        int result = Calcul<DataInfo>(data, x => x.A / x.B + x.C);
    }

    static int Calcul<T>(T data, Expression<Func<T, int>> query)
    {
        // PSEUDO CODE
        // if one property used in the query have a
        // value of -1 or -2 then return 0
        // {
        //     return 0;
        // }

        // if one property used in the query have a
        // value of 0 AND it is used on the right side of
        // a Divide operation then return -1
        // {
        //     return -1;
        // }

        // if the query respect the rules, apply the query and return the value
        return query.Compile().Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

In the previous code, the calcul want to divide A(10) with B(5) and then add C(-1). The rules said that **if one property used in the query have a value of -1 or -2, return 0**. So in this example, the value return should be -1. If the query respect the rules, then apply the query on the data and return the value.

So how can i extract the properties used in the query and test the value used in them before appying the query on the data?

Comment: You don't want to extract them from the Expression. You have the DataInfo instance right there in the method. Just check its properties. (voting to close: too localized).

Comment: the way i have presented my demo is to facilitate the comprehension. In fact, i will not know in advance what is the type of the data. This is why i need to extract what is in the query (i will not know is structure) and read the values in the data that i also not know his type! I will update my demo.

Comment: If you don't know what the type of the data is, then you can't write rules there about what its properties should be.  Either: add the rules to the type that they apply to (best if there's only one rule per type) - or pass a Func<T, int> which implements the rule to the Calcul method (maximum generic flexibility).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an ExpressionVisitor to test the property values.  Here is an example of how you could implement the logic.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // HasDivideByZero - the result should be -1
            int result1 = Calcul<DataInfo>(new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 0, C = 1 }, x => x.A / x.B + x.C);
            // HasNegative - the result should be 0
            int result2 = Calcul<DataInfo>(new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 5, C = -1 }, x => x.A / x.B + x.C);
            // the result should be 3
            int result3 = Calcul<DataInfo>(new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 5, C = 1 }, x => x.A / x.B + x.C);
        }

        static int Calcul<T>(T data, Expression<Func<T, int>> query)
        {
            if (NegativeValueChecker<T>.HasNegative(data, query))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (DivideByZeroChecker<T>.HasDivideByZero(data, query))
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return query.Compile().Invoke(data);
        }
    }

    class DivideByZeroChecker<T> : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly T _data;
        private bool _hasDivideByZero;

        public static bool HasDivideByZero(T data, Expression expression)
        {
            var visitor = new DivideByZeroChecker<T>(data);
            visitor.Visit(expression);

            return visitor._hasDivideByZero;
        }

        public DivideByZeroChecker(T data)
        {
            this._data = data;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            if (!this._hasDivideByZero && node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Divide)
            {
                var rightMemeberExpression = (MemberExpression)node.Right;
                var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)rightMemeberExpression.Member;
                var value = Convert.ToInt32(propertyInfo.GetValue(this._data, null));
                this._hasDivideByZero = value == 0;
            }

            return base.VisitBinary(node);
        }
    }

    class NegativeValueChecker<T> : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly T _data;
        public bool _hasNegative;

        public static bool HasNegative(T data, Expression expression)
        {
            var visitor = new NegativeValueChecker<T>(data);
            visitor.Visit(expression);

            return visitor._hasNegative;
        }

        public NegativeValueChecker(T data)
        {
            this._data = data;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (!this._hasNegative)
            {
                var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)node.Member;
                var value = Convert.ToInt32(propertyInfo.GetValue(this._data, null));
                this._hasNegative = value < 0;
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }

    class DataInfo
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a look at the source of **Moq** - http://code.google.com/p/moq/.