# Visiting IEnumerable<T> children

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, expressionvisitor

Here what we want to do.

We have data from the database that we need to format to make a report, including some calculation (Sum, Averages, and field to field calculation (ex : x.a / x.b)).

One of the limitations is that if, in a sum for exemple, one of the data is null, -1 or -2 we have to stop the calculation and display '-'. Since we have many reports to produce, with the same logic and many calculation in each, we want to centralise this logic. For now, the code we produce allow us to check for field to field calculation (x.a / x.b for exemple), but can't allow us to check for group total (ex: x.b / SUM(x.a))

## Test case

### Rules

- The calcul **should not be done** if one of the value used in the calcul is -1, -2 or null. In this case, return "-" if you find -1 or null, and "C" if you find -2
- If you have multiple "bad values" in the calcul, you need to respect a priority defined like this: null -> -1 -> -2. This priority is independant of the level where the value is in the calcul

### Tests

Simple calcul

```
object: new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 2, C = 4 }
calcul: x => x.A / x.B + x.C
result: 9
```

```
object: new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 2, C = -2 }
calcul: x => x.A / x.B + x.C
result: C (because you have a '-2' value in the calcul)
```

```
object: new DataInfo { A = 10, B = -2, C = null }
calcul: x => x.A / x.B + x.C
result: - (because you have a 'null' value in the calcul and it win on the -2 value)
```

Complex calcul

```
object: var list = new List();
        list.Add(new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 2, C = 4 });
        list.Add(new DataInfo { A = 6, B = 3, C = 2 });
calcul: list.Sum(x => x.A / x.B + list.Max(y => y.C))
result: 15
```

```
object: var list = new List();
        list.Add(new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 2, C = 4 });
        list.Add(new DataInfo { A = 6, B = 3, C = -2 });
calcul: list.Sum(x => x.A / x.B + list.Max(y => y.C))
result: C (because you have a '-2' value in the calcul)
```

### What we have done so far

Here the code we have to handle **simple calculs**, based on this thread:
[How to extract properties used in a Expression<Func<T, TResult>> query and test their value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508316/how-to-extract-properties-used-in-a-expressionfunct-tresult-query-and-test/8509503#8509503)

We have created a strongly type class that perform a calcul and return the result as a String.  But if any part of the expression is equal to a special value, the calculator has to return a special character.

It works well for a simple case, like this one:

```
var data = new Rapport1Data() { UnitesDisponibles = 5, ... };
var q = new Calculator<Rapport1Data>()
    .Calcul(data, y => y.UnitesDisponibles, "N0");
```

But I need to be able to perform something more complicated like:

```
IEnumerable<Rapport1Data> data = ...;
var q = new Calculator<IEnumerable<Rapport1Data>>()
    .Calcul(data, x => x.Sum(y => y.UnitesDisponibles), "N0");
```

When we start encapsulating or data in `IEnurmarable<>` we get an error:

> Object does not match target type

As we understand it, it's because the Sub-Expression `y => y.UnitesDisponibles` is being applied to the `IEnumerable` instead of the `Rapport1Data`.

How can we fix it to ensure that it will be fully recursive if we some day have complex expression like:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Rapport1Data>> data = ...;
var q = new Calculator<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Rapport1Data>>>()
    .Calcul(data,x => x.Sum(y => y.Sum(z => z.UnitesDisponibles)), "N0");
```

### Classes we've built

```
public class Calculator<T>
{
    public string Calcul(
        T data,
        Expression<Func<T, decimal?>> query,
        string format)
    {
        var rulesCheckerResult = RulesChecker<T>.Check(data, query);

        // l'ordre des vérifications est importante car il y a une gestion
        // des priorités des codes à retourner!
        if (rulesCheckerResult.HasManquante)
        {
            return TypeDonnee.Manquante.ReportValue;
        }

        if (rulesCheckerResult.HasDivisionParZero)
        {
            return TypeDonnee.DivisionParZero.ReportValue;
        }

        if (rulesCheckerResult.HasNonDiffusable)
        {
            return TypeDonnee.NonDiffusable.ReportValue;
        }

        if (rulesCheckerResult.HasConfidentielle)
        {
            return TypeDonnee.Confidentielle.ReportValue;
        }

        // if the query respect the rules, apply the query and return the
        // value
        var result = query.Compile().Invoke(data);

        return result != null
            ? result.Value.ToString(format)
            : TypeDonnee.Manquante.ReportValue;
    }
}
```

and the Custom ExpressionVisitor

```
class RulesChecker<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly T data;
    private bool hasConfidentielle = false;
    private bool hasNonDiffusable = false;
    private bool hasDivisionParZero = false;
    private bool hasManquante = false;

    public RulesChecker(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static RulesCheckerResult Check(T data, Expression expression)
    {
        var visitor = new RulesChecker<T>(data);
        visitor.Visit(expression);

        return new RulesCheckerResult(
            visitor.hasConfidentielle,
            visitor.hasNonDiffusable,
            visitor.hasDivisionParZero,
            visitor.hasManquante);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        if (!this.hasDivisionParZero &&
            node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Divide &&
            node.Right.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            var rightMemeberExpression = (MemberExpression)node.Right;
            var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)rightMemeberExpression.Member;
            var value = Convert.ToInt32(propertyInfo.GetValue(this.data, null));

            this.hasDivisionParZero = value == 0;
        }

        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        // Si l'un d'eux n'est pas à true, alors continuer de faire les tests
        if (!this.hasConfidentielle ||
            !this.hasNonDiffusable ||
            !this.hasManquante)
        {
            var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)node.Member;
            object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this.data, null);
            int? valueNumber = MTO.Framework.Common.Convert.To<int?>(value);

            // Si la valeur est à true, il n'y a pas lieu de tester davantage
            if (!this.hasManquante)
            {
                this.hasManquante =
                    valueNumber == TypeDonnee.Manquante.BdValue;
            }

            // Si la valeur est à true, il n'y a pas lieu de tester davantage
            if (!this.hasConfidentielle)
            {
                this.hasConfidentielle =
                    valueNumber == TypeDonnee.Confidentielle.BdValue;
            }

            // Si la valeur est à true, il n'y a pas lieu de tester davantage
            if (!this.hasNonDiffusable)
            {
                this.hasNonDiffusable =
                    valueNumber == TypeDonnee.NonDiffusable.BdValue;
            }
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

[UPDATE]
Adding more detail on what we want to do

Comment: Can you explain what it is exactly you are calculating?  You never actually say what you're doing and it isn't obvious when looking at your code (which is a problem).  Please add your explanation into the question body.

Comment: The `ExpressionVisitor` is designed to traverse an `Expression`, not a collection of `Expression`s.  You need to write the logic in your visitor to account for data that could be of differing types.  The way you have it written now assumes that the `data` will be something you can get values of some property from.  You should probably create a "object visitor" for the data you pass in if you want to keep this as general purpose as possible.

Comment: Looking at your code some more, I would say that you are trying to use the `ExpressionVisitor` for the wrong purposes here.  It _looks_ like you're doing some validation on some object.  You can't just throw the object at an `ExpressionVisitor` that way, it's not what it was designed for.  I think you need to reevaluate what you're doing here and consider using a different tool to do this.

Comment: Here what we want to do. We have data sent from the database that we need to format to make a report, including some calculation (Sum, Averages, etc). One of the limitations is, that if, in a sum for exemple, one of the data is null, -1 or -2 we have to stop the calculation and display '-'.

Since we have many reports to produce, with the same logic and many calculation in each, we want to centralise this logic.

For now, the code we produce allow us to check for field to field calculation (x.a / x.b for exemple), but can't allow us to check for group total (SUM(x.a) for emxemple).

Comment: I have added some tests cases to the description. I think it will be clearer for everyone to understand our needs. Btw, i'm working on the same project as Groumy! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to change to get this to work:

- Create a new ExpressionVisitor that will preprocess your expression to execute the aggregates.
- Use the new ExpressionVisitor in the Calculator.Calcul method.
- Modify the RulesChecker to include an override for the VisitConstant method.  This new method needs to include the same logic that is in the VisitMember method.
- Modify the RulesChecker VisitBinary method to check the divide by zero condition for ConstantExpressions.

Here is a rough example of what I think needs to be done.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    internal static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main() {
            var calculator = new Calculator();

            //// DivideByZero - the result should be -1
            var data1 = new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 0, C = 1 };
            Expression<Func<DataInfo, decimal?>> expression1 = x => x.A / x.B + x.C;
            var result1 = calculator.Calcul(data1, expression1, "N0");

            //// Negative 1 - the result should be -
            var data2 = new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 5, C = -1 };
            Expression<Func<DataInfo, decimal?>> expression2 = x => x.A / x.B + x.C;
            var result2 = calculator.Calcul(data2, expression2, "N0");

            //// Negative 2 - the result should be C
            var data3 = new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 5, C = -2 };
            Expression<Func<DataInfo, decimal?>> expression3 = x => x.A / x.B + x.C;
            var result3 = calculator.Calcul(data3, expression3, "N0");

            //// the result should be 3
            var data4 = new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 5, C = 1 };
            Expression<Func<DataInfo, decimal?>> expression4 = x => x.A / x.B + x.C;
            var result4 = calculator.Calcul(data4, expression4, "N0");

            //// DivideByZero - the result should be -1
            var data5 = new List<DataInfo> {
                                    new DataInfo {A = 10, B = 0, C = 1},
                                    new DataInfo {A = 10, B = 0, C = 1}
                        };

            Expression<Func<IEnumerable<DataInfo>, decimal?>> expression5 = x => x.Sum(y => y.A) / x.Sum(y => y.B) + x.Sum(y => y.C);
            var result5 = calculator.Calcul(data5, expression5, "N0");

            //// the result should be 4
            var data6 = new List<DataInfo> {
                                    new DataInfo {A = 10, B = 5, C = 1},
                                    new DataInfo {A = 10, B = 5, C = 1}
                        };

            Expression<Func<IEnumerable<DataInfo>, decimal?>> expression6 = x => x.Sum(y => y.A) / x.Sum(y => y.B) + x.Sum(y => y.C);
            var result6 = calculator.Calcul(data6, expression6, "N0");

            //// the result should be -
            var data7 = new List<DataInfo> {
                                    new DataInfo {A = 10, B = 5, C = -1},
                                    new DataInfo {A = 10, B = 5, C = 1}
                        };

            Expression<Func<IEnumerable<DataInfo>, decimal?>> expression7 = x => x.Sum(y => y.A) / x.Sum(y => y.B) + x.Sum(y => y.C);
            var result7 = calculator.Calcul(data7, expression7, "N0");

            //// the result should be 14
            var c1 = 1;
            var c2 = 2;

            var data8 = new DataInfo { A = 10, B = 1, C = 1 };
            Expression<Func<DataInfo, decimal?>> expression8 = x => x.A / x.B + x.C + c1 + c2;
            var result8 = calculator.Calcul(data8, expression8, "N0");
        }
    }

    public class Calculator {
        public string Calcul<T>(T data, LambdaExpression query, string format) {
            string reportValue;

            if (HasIssue(data, query, out reportValue)) {
                return reportValue;
            }

            // executes the aggregates
            query = (LambdaExpression)ExpressionPreProcessor.PreProcessor(data, query);

            // checks the rules against the results of the aggregates
            if (HasIssue(data, query, out reportValue)) {
                return reportValue;
            }

            Delegate lambda = query.Compile();
            decimal? result = (decimal?)lambda.DynamicInvoke(data);

            return result != null
                ? result.Value.ToString(format)
                : TypeDonnee.Manquante.ReportValue;
        }

        private bool HasIssue(object data, LambdaExpression query, out string reportValue) {
            reportValue = null;

            var rulesCheckerResult = RulesChecker.Check(data, query);

            if (rulesCheckerResult.HasManquante) {
                reportValue = TypeDonnee.Manquante.ReportValue;
            }

            if (rulesCheckerResult.HasDivisionParZero) {
                reportValue = TypeDonnee.DivisionParZero.ReportValue;
            }

            if (rulesCheckerResult.HasNonDiffusable) {
                reportValue = TypeDonnee.NonDiffusable.ReportValue;
            }

            if (rulesCheckerResult.HasConfidentielle) {
                reportValue = TypeDonnee.Confidentielle.ReportValue;
            }

            return reportValue != null;
        }
    }

    internal class ExpressionPreProcessor : ExpressionVisitor {
        private readonly object _source;

        public static Expression PreProcessor(object source, Expression expression) {
            if (!IsValidSource(source)) {
                return expression;
            }

            var visitor = new ExpressionPreProcessor(source);

            return visitor.Visit(expression);
        }

        private static bool IsValidSource(object source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return false;
            }

            var type = source.GetType();

            return type.IsGenericType && type.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null;
        }

        public ExpressionPreProcessor(object source) {
            this._source = source;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node) {
            if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Enumerable) && node.Arguments.Count == 2) {

                switch (node.Method.Name) {
                    case "Count":
                    case "Min":
                    case "Max":
                    case "Sum":
                    case "Average":
                        var lambda = node.Arguments[1] as LambdaExpression;
                        var lambaDelegate = lambda.Compile();
                        var value = node.Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { this._source, lambaDelegate });

                        return Expression.Constant(value);
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }

    internal class RulesChecker : ExpressionVisitor {
        private readonly object data;
        private bool hasConfidentielle = false;
        private bool hasNonDiffusable = false;
        private bool hasDivisionParZero = false;
        private bool hasManquante = false;

        public RulesChecker(object data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public static RulesCheckerResult Check(object data, Expression expression) {
            if (IsIEnumerable(data)) {
                var result = new RulesCheckerResult(false, false, false, false);

                IEnumerable dataItems = (IEnumerable)data;

                foreach (object dataItem in dataItems) {
                    result = MergeResults(result, GetResults(dataItem, expression));
                }

                return result;

            }
            else {
                return GetResults(data, expression);
            }
        }

        private static RulesCheckerResult MergeResults(RulesCheckerResult results1, RulesCheckerResult results2) {
            var hasConfidentielle = results1.HasConfidentielle || results2.HasConfidentielle;
            var hasDivisionParZero = results1.HasDivisionParZero || results2.HasDivisionParZero;
            var hasManquante = results1.HasManquante || results2.HasManquante;
            var hasNonDiffusable = results1.HasNonDiffusable || results2.HasNonDiffusable;

            return new RulesCheckerResult(hasConfidentielle, hasNonDiffusable, hasDivisionParZero, hasManquante);
        }

        private static RulesCheckerResult GetResults(object data, Expression expression) {
            var visitor = new RulesChecker(data);
            visitor.Visit(expression);

            return new RulesCheckerResult(
                visitor.hasConfidentielle,
                visitor.hasNonDiffusable,
                visitor.hasDivisionParZero,
                visitor.hasManquante);
        }

        private static bool IsIEnumerable(object source) {
            if (source == null) {
                return false;
            }

            var type = source.GetType();

            return type.IsGenericType && type.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node) {
            if (!this.hasDivisionParZero && node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Divide) {
                if (node.Right.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess) {
                    var rightMemeberExpression = (MemberExpression)node.Right;
                    var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)rightMemeberExpression.Member;
                    var value = Convert.ToInt32(propertyInfo.GetValue(this.data, null));

                    this.hasDivisionParZero = value == 0;
                }

                if (node.Right.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant) {
                    var rightConstantExpression = (ConstantExpression)node.Right;
                    var value = Convert.ToInt32(rightConstantExpression.Value);

                    this.hasDivisionParZero = value == 0;
                }

            }

            return base.VisitBinary(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node) {
            this.CheckValue(this.ConvertToNullableInt(node.Value));

            return base.VisitConstant(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node) {
            if (!this.hasConfidentielle || !this.hasNonDiffusable || !this.hasManquante) {
                var propertyInfo = node.Member as PropertyInfo;

                if (propertyInfo != null) {
                    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this.data, null);

                    this.CheckValue(this.ConvertToNullableInt(value));
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        private void CheckValue(int? value) {
            if (!this.hasManquante) {
                this.hasManquante = value == TypeDonnee.Manquante.BdValue;
            }

            if (!this.hasConfidentielle) {
                this.hasConfidentielle = value == TypeDonnee.Confidentielle.BdValue;
            }

            if (!this.hasNonDiffusable) {
                this.hasNonDiffusable = value == TypeDonnee.NonDiffusable.BdValue;
            }
        }

        private int? ConvertToNullableInt(object value) {
            if (!value.GetType().IsPrimitive) {
                return int.MinValue;
            }

            // MTO.Framework.Common.Convert.To<int?>(value);
            return (int?)value;
        }
    }

    class RulesCheckerResult {
        public bool HasConfidentielle { get; private set; }
        public bool HasNonDiffusable { get; private set; }
        public bool HasDivisionParZero { get; private set; }
        public bool HasManquante { get; private set; }

        public RulesCheckerResult(bool hasConfidentielle, bool hasNonDiffusable, bool hasDivisionParZero, bool hasManquante) {
            this.HasConfidentielle = hasConfidentielle;
            this.HasNonDiffusable = hasNonDiffusable;
            this.HasDivisionParZero = hasDivisionParZero;
            this.HasManquante = hasManquante;
        }
    }

    class TypeDonnee {
        public static readonly TypeValues Manquante = new TypeValues(null, "-");
        public static readonly TypeValues Confidentielle = new TypeValues(-1, "-");
        public static readonly TypeValues NonDiffusable = new TypeValues(-2, "C");
        public static readonly TypeValues DivisionParZero = new TypeValues(0, "-1");
    }

    class TypeValues {
        public int? BdValue { get; set; }
        public string ReportValue { get; set; }

        public TypeValues(int? bdValue, string reportValue) {
            this.BdValue = bdValue;
            this.ReportValue = reportValue;
        }
    }

    class DataInfo {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public int C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a very good attempt but your code doesnt work for all cases. If you take the data6 and change one of the C value for -1, the result should be "-". Presently, the code return 2 because you have evaluated the Sum(x => x.C), in fact -1 + 1 = 0, before checking it for special characters. This is very important that **all values** are checked for special characters **before** doing any calculation.

Comment: Ah, I missed that condition.  I modified the code to include that scenario.

Comment: Very impressive! Thank you very much for your help! This is exactly the solution that we wanted! The guy that opened the question is in vacation for the hollydays. Don't worry, he will accept your answer as soon as he return.

Comment: There's a little bug in the code if you use a variable inside the query. Suppose that `var1 = 2` in this expression: `x => x.A / x.B + x.C + var1`, you will get a System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo casting error. I tried to flatten the query to just keep the real variables for the calculs but it didnt work. If you have a quick idea on this it would be very appreciated... again :)

Comment: I just spent more than half my work week in requirements meetings so you have to forgive me when I say it wasn’t a bug with my code but a lack of requirements :).  Anyway, assuming that you can validate the variables outside of the RuleChecker Visitor I have a simple fix for you.  I updated the code to include a little extra type checking.

Comment: I'm really sorry if i've said "bug"! The word was mischosen. I had to work with your code this week and i had many bugs to solves to make it work correctly, not because of you but, like you've said, because of lack of requirements. I realize that working with ExpressionVisitor is really complex. Just an example is if you use different type of value (int * decimal / double), the DivideByZero that we want to check will not work because of the Convert expression that is everywhere. I have opened a new question for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764662

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're looking for a 'recursive sum' function.  Might I suggest something like this?

```
    var q = new Calculator<Rapport1Data>()
.Calcul(data, y => RecursiveCalc(y), "N0");

    double RecursiveCalc(object toCalc)
    {
         var asRapport = toCalc as Rapport1Data;
         if (asRapport != null)
             return asRapport.UnitesDisponibles;

         var asEnumerable = toCalc as IEnumerable;
         if (asEnumerable != null)
             return asEnumerable.Sum(y => RecursiveCalc(y));


         return 0; // handle a condition for unexpected types
    }
```

*note: code not tested, might not even compile